# createdb: too many command line arguments (first is template0)

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I was told to create a database with the following command:

```
createdb -U $USER --locale=en_US.utf-8 -E utf-8 -O $USER mangodb -T template0
```

But I get the error "createdb: too many command line arguments (first is template0)". What's wrong with this command?

Comment: Echo the command and see what the `CREATE DATABASE` statement looks like.

Comment: Add `-e` to your `createdb` command.  It should output what is really being executed, which is `CREATE DATABASE ...`

Comment: I did  "createdb -U $USER --locale=en_US.utf-8 -E utf-8 -O $USER mangodb -T template0 -e" and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: I didn't say this would fix your problem, I said it would echo (output) the actual command which Postgres is executing.  That being said, please update your question with what the echo is showing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html) the database name (and possible description) comes last. So `-T template0` has to come before the `mangodb` database name:

```
createdb -U $USER --locale=en_US.utf-8 -E utf-8 -T template0 mangodb
```

The option `-T template0` is only required if `template1` has an encoding other than `utf-8`. Otherwise you should probably omit the option such that you would use `template1` which tends to be more useful than `template0` because it has more extensions loaded and other site-specific data.

Note also that `-O $USER` is superfluous because of `-U $USER`: the connected user is the owner of the new database by default.